# Google Url fetch service sudenly start to fail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, urlfetch

I've been using the google code Url fetch service in a script attached to docs spreadsheet, and it had been working for more than a year. But suddenly, upon migration of docs to google drive, the service start to fail.

This is the format:

```
var url='xyz.com?command=xxx'
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

The failure report keeps saying..."unexpected error", while nothing has changed in the code 4 more than a year.

Pls What should I do to put things in order?

Comment: what happens if you try to open url in browser or try to invoke it via command line?

Comment: It's probably that google drive changed something, not the UrlFetch service

Comment: @PeterKnego. I opened the url in browser, and it responded with the expected response. So it means the URL is working file, and the problem is from google.

Comment: My wild guess: you are most probably logged-in in the browser so it let's you through, while URLFetch fails. Clear cookies in your browser  for this domain and try again. Every request in GDrive must be authenticated (=user must pass OAuth procedure), even for public files.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for your interesting comment about gdrive requests and authentication. I also use URLFtech in a docs spreadsheet to access GAE using a UTC SHA with a timeout to authenticate. By the way: this still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray!

I got it!

Google was the problem.

I've been using the url starting with the API server IP, and it worked fine. Now, the fetch service stopped fetching using IP address. When I attempted to use the domain name in place of the IP address, it worked fine again.

Alhamdulillah!

But it would be good if someone here knows google guys and could inform them of this anomaly. This problem started to me around the same time I was migrated to the "DRIVE" service, away from the old "DOCS".

Thanks all, and have a blessed day.